# Interaction between 2 android devices

Tags: android, sockets

Can i send a command through a Server(android device) to a client(another android device) with sockets? A command like to make some buttons non-clicable?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data from one phone to the server - the server can then push content to the other device if it is signed into the service (this makes the device unique). The incoming data and trigger an action, in this case to make some buttons non-clickable.

Comment: the Server in my case is another android device. I send data to the Server. How the Server sends back a command(system call, i dont know) to make the buttons non clickable? What the server would send?